# black screen after social login with Ionic Angular and Capacitor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-oauth, facebook-login, capacitor

I've been stuck on a problem for a few days.
I am developing an App that uses Ionic Angular and Capacitor where login with Google and Facebook social networks is provided.

> ionic info
>
> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.1 (/Users/incal/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.2/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
> Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.1.4
> @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.2.6
> @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.2.6
> @angular/cli                  : 13.2.6
> @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0
>
> Capacitor:
>
> Capacitor CLI      : 3.5.1
> @capacitor/android : 3.5.1
> @capacitor/core    : 3.5.1
> @capacitor/ios     : 3.5.1
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
> native-run (update available: 1.7.0) : 1.5.0
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v14.19.2 (/Users/incal/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.2/bin/node)
> npm    : 8.17.0
> OS     : macOS Monterey

I use packages:

> "@ capacitor-community / facebook-login": "^ 3.4.0",
> "@ codetrix-studio / capacitor-google-auth": "^ 3.1.3",

The login procedures work correctly the problem is that in the end, on iOs, you get a black screen.
From the logs you can see that the app continues to run smoothly but the interface is covered by what looks like a layer

Anyone have any suggestions?

regards,
Maurizio

Answer (score 0):

the problem was a cordova AdMob plugin that break iOS layout constrains,
i replace it with capacitor-community/admob, the issue disappear